# Can't disable order joins in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Postgresql provides a parameter  [join_collapse_limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-joins.html) = 1 to disable order of joins. But when I set the parameter and reset the server, the query plan is not changed and there still is order join optimization. My query FROM table is like this

```
FROM 
student as group_A, 
student as group_B,
student as group_C
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output please. Als, PostgreSQL version? And how exactly are you setting `join_collapse_limit` - what process are you following? (If you're setting it in `postgresql.conf` - don't! Set it per-transaction with `SET LOCAL join_collapse_limit=1` instead).

Answer (score 1):

If users want to use  join_collapse_limit = 1  to disable join reordering, explicit JOINS must be provided in the query. For example, the above FROM table should be

```
FROM 
student as group_A CROSS JOIN
student as group_B CROSS JOIN
student as group_C
WHERE ...
```